# consulta de comando o forma de hacerlo

Tags: r

tengo una consulta de programación R, si tengo y lista de caracteres, como cuento el numero de caracteres?

ejemplo:

```
A=c("a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","d","f","f","f","f","a","a","a","b","a")
```

A partir de esta lista A, deseo sacar un subconjunto que contenga de los elementos de A(llamado B) pero en función del número de repeticiones, ejemplo(sacar elementos que se repitan mayor a 4 veces y decir cuántas veces se repiten)

La respuesta debe sale algo en tabla B

```
elemento   repeticiones
b               8
a               5
```

Comment: Bienvenido user237481 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo tuyo es básicamente una tabla de frecuencias, por lo que con R base lo más simple es usar `table()`:

```
table(A)
A
a b d f 
5 8 1 4
```

Para seleccionar por cantidad:

```
ta[ta>4]
A
a b 
5 8
```

Lógicamente la salida es un objeto de la clase `table` seguramente es mucho más cómodo trabajarlo como `data.frame`:

```
as.data.frame(ta[ta>4])

  A Freq
1 a    5
2 b    8
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, ahora logre entenderlo :)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear un dataframe con una columna con tu lista de caracteres y una cantidad de filas equivalente a cada valor unico de tu lista

```
library(tidyverse)

data_ejemplo = data.frame(A = rep(paste(A, collapse = "-"), length(unique(A))),
  categorias = unique(A))
```

y luego contar cuantas veces se repite cada valor unico de tu lista con:

```
data_ejemplo %>%
  mutate(n_rep = str_count(A, categorias)) %>%
  filter(n_rep > 4)
```

y con el filter quedarte solo con los casos con mayor a 4 repeticiones